# Retrieve integer from a complex string

Tags: java

I have a code which read the content of a certain file. The file begin like this :

```
J-549 J-628 J-379 J-073 J-980 vs J-548 J-034 J-127 J-625 J-667\
J-152 J-681 J-922 J-079 J-103 vs J-409 J-552 J-253 J-286 J-711\
J-934 J-367 J-549 J-169 J-569 vs J-407 J-429 J-445 J-935 J-578\
```

I would like to store each integer in an array of size 270 (number of line) x 10 (integer at each line).

I am not using the correct regex. Here is a piece of my code :

```
String strLine;
int[] id = new int[10];//list ID of each line
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    // Print the content on the console

    strLine = strLine.replaceAll("J-", "");
    strLine = strLine.replaceAll(" vs ", " ");
    String[] teamString = strLine.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(id[i] + " ");
}
```

I was thinking of removing the "J-" and " vs " but it seems to be a bad idea.
The console prints :

```
549 628 379 073 980 548 034 127 625 667\ 
152 681 922 079 103 409 552 253 286 711\ 
934 367 549 169 569 407 429 445 935 578\
```

Does someone can help me to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: so your each array element will have what : `549628379073980 548034127625667` or `549`

Comment: What is the expected result? Are you asking how to also remove ``\``?

Comment: No he is asking alternative of replacing

Comment: I want to retrieve each integer separately and I have the problem with the character '/'.

Comment: I would like to use another regex which can split the string StrLine. I want to have an array which contains only the IDs of players (integer). The backlash was a problem when I tried to store the end of a line in an integer array. The print if for debugging (I wanted to see how was the string final). I have forgotten to said that my final array must be an Integer type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for replacing \ use escaping char \

```
String s[] ="J-549 J-628 J-379 J-073 J-980 vs J-548 J-034 J-127 J-625 J-667\\"
                    .replace("\\", "")
                    .replace("J-", "")
                    .replace(" vs ", " ")
                    .split(" ");
//System.out.println(s);
int[] id = new int[10];
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    id[i] = Integer.valueOf(s[i]);
}
for(int i=0; i<id.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(id[i]);
}
```

Result:

```
549
628
379
73
980
548
34
127
625
667
```

Comment: Using `replaceAll` makes sense only when we are using regex syntax. For literals it is safer to use `replace` (it also replaces all occurrences despite lack of `All` suffix) to avoid potential problems with regex syntax like when we would like to replace `+`, `*`, `(`, `[` and other regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of replacing all the characters you don't want, you could just use a Regex to match those which you do want.

```
Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("J-(\\d+)");
String strLine;
int[] id = new int[10]; // list ID of each line

// read file line by line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher lineMatcher = idPattern.matcher(strLine);

    // find and parse every ID on this line
    for (int i = 0; matcher.find() && i < id.length; i++) {
        String idStr = matcher.group(1); // Gets the capture group 1 "(\\d+)" - group 0 is the entire match "J-(\\d+)"
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idStr, 10);
        id[i] = id;
        System.out.print(id + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

The regex `J-(\d+)` matches a part of string which starts with "J-" and ends in one or more numbers. The parentheses around the number create a *capture group*, which we can access directly instead of having to replace "J-".

If you're sure that you want to parse the IDs as integers, notice that when parsed, "073" becomes 73. Not sure if that makes a difference for you. Also, if there *may* be more than 10 IDs on one line, use an `ArrayList` and add the IDs there instead of placing them in a fixed-size array.

Comment: Your solution is interesting but I have found the solution with another post before. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure! If in the future you bump into a similar problem but there's a lot more characters to remove or they intersect with the useful data you want, you'll probably want to match & find instead of replace.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use regex of `\d+` to capture the number terms and retrieve all them to a List or array whatever you want.

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(strLine);

 while (m.find()) {
    // print the number or store it in array or whatever
    System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap entire regex with parenthesis. Also placing optional `\\.?` in the middle of `\\d* \\d+` could cause problems like [Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Possible improvement in this case would be simple `\\d+`, of if you want to include optional `.fraction` something like `\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`.

Answer (score 0):

use `strLine.replace("\\", "");` one more time.